# Multiple Core Data instances

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I'm designing an app that has a 'work offline' feature. When this feature is activated, the data from an external database gets synced with the Core Data database on the device. The problem that I'm having concerns multiple users.

My application also implements a permission-system in which it is possible for one user to have access to data that another user can't read. My question is, is it possible to create an instance of my Core Data schema for every user that logs in? This way, I can switch databases for every user and they can't interact with data from other users.

I'm ofcourse also open to alternative suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chris, you can do it in  some ways, this one is what I did in one of my apps and  I recommend:

- When creating the NSPersistentStore, make that the file name depends on the user id or the username. Wait to get the user id from your server in order to create it. If the app is in the logged out state, don't call the NSPersistentStore, but just in case, return nil if the current user id doesn't exists;
- Every time a user logs in, initiate the NSManagedObjectContext based on the NSPersistentStore above;
- Every time a user logs out, make sure to set to `nil` all the Core Data stack (NSManagedObjectContext, NSPersistentStore and NSManagedObjectModel), so all the NSManagedObjects are removed from memory.

This way one user should not be able to access other's data, but I'm not sure about schemas.

Comment: Looks great! Can I create the NSPersistentStore programmatically on login or do I need to know the user id beforehand?

Comment: Check the edit in the first part. Please accept answer and/or upvote if it helped and solved your problem.